# Cкрыть и показать картинку при клике

Tags: jquery

есть 4 блока в каждом из которых находится картинка.
Каким образом можно сделать так чтобы изначально не было видно изображений во всех четырех блоках, 
но при клике на блок появлялась картинка внутри него а при клике на другой блок картинка исчезала из предыдущего блока.

```css
body{
text-align:center;
font-size: 20px;
}

img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
} 

.block-1{
border:1px solid red;
padding: 10px;
width: 300px;
position:relative;
margin:3%;
} 

.block-2{
border:1px solid red;
padding: 10px;
width: 300px;
position:relative;
margin:3%;
}  

.block-3{
border:1px solid red;
padding: 10px;
width: 300px;
position:relative;
margin:3%;
}
 
.block-4{
border:1px solid red;
padding: 10px;
width: 300px;
position:relative;
margin:3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1">
 1 блок  
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7DhJrj/1499960790146478733.jpg"/>
</div>


<div class="block-2"> 
 2 блок    
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7DhJrj/1499960790146478733.jpg"/>
</div>


<div class="block-3">  
 3 блок   
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7DhJrj/1499960790146478733.jpg"/>
</div>


<div class="block-4"> 
 4 блок    
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7DhJrj/1499960790146478733.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В смысле вот так?

```js
$('img').hide();
$('div').click(function() {
  $('img').each((i,c)=>c!=$(this).find('img')[0]?$(c).hide():$(c).toggle());
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  1 блок
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7DhJrj/1499960790146478733.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="block">
  2 блок
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7DhJrj/1499960790146478733.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="block">
  3 блок
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7DhJrj/1499960790146478733.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="block">
  4 блок
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7DhJrj/1499960790146478733.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!
А в чем разница между
 $(this).find('img').toggle() и
 $('img').each((i,c)=>c!=$(this).find('img')[0]?$(c).hide():$(c).toggle());

Comment: toggle() - скрывает/показывает блок в зависимости от текущего состояния, а hide() - всегда только скрывает. Конкретно здесь $('img').each((i,c)=>c!=$(this).find('img')[0]?$(c).hide():$(c).toggle()); - мы получаем все изображения на странице, проходим по ним и если изображение не относится к блоку по которому мы нажали, то вызываем метод hide(), если изображение принадлежит данному блоку, который вызвал событие click, то вызываем метод toggle().

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).find('img').toggle()
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block-1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3%;
}

.block-2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3%;
}

.block-3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3%;
}

.block-4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-1">
  1 блок
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7DhJrj/1499960790146478733.jpg" />
</div>


<div class="block-2">
  2 блок
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7DhJrj/1499960790146478733.jpg" />
</div>


<div class="block-3">
  3 блок
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7DhJrj/1499960790146478733.jpg" />
</div>


<div class="block-4">
  4 блок
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7DhJrj/1499960790146478733.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Используйте метод toggle().